# Why does Qt Creator find the typedef, but not the build process?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I am trying to use an external library in my Qt Creator project. I am building it with Visual C++ on Windows.

I added this to my qmake file:

```
# Include libspotify
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libspotify\\include
LIBS     += -LC:\\libspotify\\lib -llibspotify
```

Then I went to use some typedef'd structs from the library:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <libspotify/api.h>

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    sp_session_config spConfig;
    sp_session spSession;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Now in the IDE editor, the syntax highlight marks sp_session_config and sp_session in purple indicating the editor can find those typedefs fine (if it doesn't find a definition it leaves the text black).

But when I build I get this:

```
mainwindow.h:32: error: C2079: 'MainWindow::spSession' uses undefined struct 'sp_session'
```

Now I know the compiler is finding the api.h file, because if I change it to a bogus filename it spits out a file not found error.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The header file defines the struct like this:

```
extern "C" {
typedef struct sp_session sp_session; ///< Representation of a session
}
```

Comment: Can't say that this is the issue, but an 'extern "C" { }' around the include might be in order since libspotify looks like a C library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a declaration for a typedef to `struct sp_session` but `struct sp_session` is an incomplete type.  In order for the `QMainWindow` class to have a `sp_session` member, the type must be complete (ie., you need a declaration that also defines what members `struct sp_session` has).

If that's not possible, you might be able to restructure things so that `class QMainWindow` has an `sp_struct*` or `sp_struct&` as a member instead.

Comment: Thanks for that! It turned out that I actually wanted to define `sp_session * spSession`

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I actually meant to `sp_session * spSession`!